# What's a good dark colored Visual Studio color-scheme that plays well with Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, color-scheme

I've finally started playing around with Resharper and am loving it!  The only problem is that I use a modified Zenburn color-scheme in Visual Studio 2008 and am finding some of the resharper suggestions and tooltips difficult to read.  Do you use a dark backgrounded color-scheme in Visual Studio with Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using modified http://flanders.co.nz/2007/07/18/dark-visual-studio-scheme-with-resharper-support/ scheme for a long time. The only problem I have - it is needed to modify it, when new version of Resharper is installed.

Hopefully it is very easy to fix. Go to Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors, find bad-looking display items, which is started with "resharper" word and adjust it.